# Boostrap with SELECT and icon on the same row

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place those controls on the same level. I want to have the save button bottom aligned with the  element.

[image]

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(f => f.DatabaseName, "Database Name")
            @Html.DropDownListFor(f => f.DatabaseName, ViewBag.DatabaseList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "dbs form-control", style = "margin-bottom:20px" })
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Save
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Save
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at :  http://www.bootply.com/yHUeAcHaRX

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group">
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i>Save</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is close but not aligning.

Comment: Do you have any custom css effecting those elements? Using a clean copy of boostrap and no extra css it appears to line up for me, what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
<div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="form-group">

            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Save
          </div>
          </div>
</div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Save
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```